# Laravel storing temporary filename in database

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

The upload script is working, the file also gets saved by the correct/desired name. However, while storing data in database, it stores .tmp filename instead

controller code:

```
public function store(CreateChapterRequest $request)
{
    if($request['chapter_content_type']==6) {
        //upload file
        $record_save = $this->processFile($request->file('chapter_document'));
        $request['chapter_document']=$record_save;
    }
    Chapter::create($request->all());
}

protected function processFile($requestData)
{
    $input['chapter_document'] = time().'.'.$requestData->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/chapters/');
    $requestData->move($destinationPath, $input['chapter_document']);
    return $input['chapter_document'];
}
```

It's storing file name as `C:\project\xampp\tmp\phpD837.tmp`. What's wrong?

Comment: So the file is stored correcly but you receive the wrong filepath/name.
Could you dd the $record_save variable?

Answer (score 0):

It works with `$record=new Chapter(); $record->save($request->all());` but not with `::create()`

Don't know why!